# How do I find "mergefields" using javascript and regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

My "mergefields" look like this [@something].

Having a string like this..

```
[@name] is [@age] years old and his favorite color is [@color].
```

**Since my user enters the mergefields, I don't know the mergefields.**

How can I in javascript + regex find all [@...] fields?

Thanks

Comment: And what did you try? And what *something* can contain? Spaces, hyphens?

Comment: I'm a total noob at regex, so I don't know where to start or end. And trying google it just made me more confused.

Comment: OK, what is your current code at least?

Comment: @Raghavendra ... then they could close this site right?

Comment: @MojoDK see the policies of site http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Raghavendra - what did I do wrong to upset you? Two other people have helped me troumendous with two great answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching innermost braces with regex or strpos?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455597/matching-innermost-braces-with-regex-or-strpos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following regex to extract `[@...]` pattern from your string.

```
/(\[@\w+])/g
```

**Explanation**

1. `()`: Matching group
2. `\[`: Matches `[` literal, need to escape by preceding `\`
3. `@`: Matches `@` literal
4. `\w+`: Matches alphanumeric characters and underscore `_` one or more times
5. `]`: Matches `]` literal
6. `g`: Global flag. Get all the matches

**Visualization**

[image]

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rI1pC1/1)

```js
var str = '[@name] is [@age] years old and his favorite color is [@color].';

var matches = str.match(/(\[@\w+])/g);

document.write(matches);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: When writing an answer for a "total noob" you must include a thorough description of why your code should work.

Comment: @stribizhev Yes, I was doing the same thing

Comment: Good, but `]` outside of a character class does not have to (and thus should not) be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Here how can you make it:

```js
var s = '[@name] is [@age] years old and his favorite color is [@color]'

s.match(/\[(@[^\]]*)\]/g)
# [@name],[@age],[@color]
```

### Explanation

`match` function will return an array of matching substrings.

The regexp `/\[(@[^\]]*)\]/g` means:

- `/` are regexp boundaries
- ending `g` means *match globally* which is a greedy regexp.
- the rest means:

  - an open square bracket `\[`
  - followed by an `@` and everything `[ ... ]` that is not `^` a closed square bracket `\]`.
  - followed by a closed square bracket `\]`
  - the `( ... )` are group delimiters, enclose the part of the string you are interested in as output.

Comment: When writing an answer for a "total noob" you must include a thorough description of why your code should work.

Comment: Right, I've updated the answer with some explainations